# Reproducir y pausar sonido con el mismo botón en Arduino uno y sparkfun mp3 shield

Tags: arduino

Tengo un *Arduino* 1 v3 y una *sparkfun mp3 player shield v15*. Necesito que con un mismo botón (un botón arcade) al pulsarlo la primera vez dispare un mp3 y al pulsarlo otra vez se pare. Así en *loop*, intente copiar de un proyecto de ejemplo de *sparkfun* pero no soy capaz de que suene.

```
#include <SPI.h>             // SPI library
#include <SdFat.h>           // SDFat Library
//#include <SdFatUtil.h>     // SDFat Util Library
#include <SFEMP3Shield.h>    // Mp3 Shield Library

SFEMP3Shield MP3player;


int reedSwitch = 4;  
boolean active = false;


void setup() {
  pinMode(reedSwitch, INPUT); //Reed Switch
  digitalWrite(reedSwitch, HIGH); //turn on internal pullups for reed input

  MP3player.begin();
  MP3player.setVolume(0x00, 0x00); //set volume
}

void loop() 
{
  
    if (digitalRead(reedSwitch) == HIGH && !active)//when door opens
    {
      active = true;
      MP3player.stopTrack();
      MP3player.playTrack(1);
    }
    else if (digitalRead(reedSwitch) == LOW && active)//
    {
      active = false;
      MP3player.stopTrack();
  
    }

  delay(100);
}
```

Comment: ¿De donde sale la música? ¿No deberías inicializar el SD?

Answer (score 0):

La música si esta en la sd, la nombre como 1.mp3 he probado con esto pero tampoco va.

```
#include <SPI.h>           // SPI library
#include <SdFat.h>         // SDFat Library
//#include <SdFatUtil.h>     // SDFat Util Library
#include <SFEMP3Shield.h>  // Mp3 Shield Library

SdFat sd; // Create object to handle SD functions

SFEMP3Shield MP3player; // Create Mp3 library object
// These variables are used in the MP3 initialization to set up
// some stereo options:
const uint8_t volume = 0; // MP3 Player volume 0=max, 255=lowest (off)
const uint16_t monoMode = 1;  // Mono setting 0=off, 3=max
/* Pin setup */
int reedSwitch = 4;  
boolean active = false;


void setup() {
  pinMode(reedSwitch, INPUT); //Reed Switch
  digitalWrite(reedSwitch, HIGH); //turn on internal pullups for reed input
  Serial.begin(9600);  // initialize serial communication
  initSD();  // Initialize the SD card
  initMP3Player(); // Initialize the MP3 Shield
}

void loop() 
{
  
    if (digitalRead(reedSwitch) == HIGH && !active)//when door opens
    {
      active = true;
      MP3player.stopTrack();
      MP3player.playTrack(1);
    }
    else if (digitalRead(reedSwitch) == LOW && active)//
    {
      active = false;
      MP3player.stopTrack();
  
    }

  delay(100);
}

// initSD() initializes the SD card and checks for an error.
void initSD()
{
  //Initialize the SdCard.
  if(!sd.begin(SD_SEL, SPI_HALF_SPEED)) 
    sd.initErrorHalt();
  if(!sd.chdir("/")) 
    sd.errorHalt("sd.chdir");
}

// initMP3Player() sets up all of the initialization for the
// MP3 Player Shield. It runs the begin() function, checks
// for errors, applies a patch if found, and sets the volume/
// stero mode.
void initMP3Player()
{
  uint8_t result = MP3player.begin(); // init the mp3 player shield
  if(result != 0) // check result, see readme for error codes.
  {
    // Error checking can go here!
  }

}
```